# C#: Cannot bind to property or column name on DataSource

Tags: c#, data-binding

[image]

I am getting thuis error message when I launch my C# Winforms application. It only started recently, and I cannot isolate exactly what change caused it to begin. Can anyone suggestwhere I should investigate next?

The Exception details are shown here:
Type: `System.ArgumentException`
Data: `{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}`
HResult:   `-2147024809`
Message:
`Cannot bind to the property or column Name on the DataSource.`
`Parameter name: dataMember`
ParamName:   `"dataMember"`
Source:     `"System.Windows.Forms"`
Stack Trace:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.set_Visible(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.UpdateTabSelection(Boolean updateFocus)
at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Also, in the Target Site details, I find these errors:

`Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityCritical cannot be called in this context.`
`Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecuritySafeCritical cannot be called in this context.`
`Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityTransparent cannot be called in this context.`
`Method System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_MethodImplementationFlags cannot be called in this context.`
`'((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)($exception).TargetSite).ReflectedType' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'`
`Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnTypeCustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.`

Comment: have you gotten a solution for this error?  I'm facing a similar issue and I can't figure out whats causing it or how its happening.

Comment: This is history now for me, I don't even remember what project it occurred on, but if I recall accurately, it turned out to be that I was trying to bind a property of a Winforms screen element to a property of a C# class that was not an atomic simple type. And I solved it by creating another, read-only *calculated* property on the class that was based on the more complex property, but was of an atomic, simple type. First, try to bind to a calculated property defined to return a constant value, then if that works, change the *get* code to return what you actually need.